# Update associated object inside Entity via @Query in spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I want to update an associated object inside Entity via @Query of spring data JPA.
Is it possible to do so?

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person{
   
   @Id
   private Long id;
   
   @OneToOne
   @NotNull
   @JoinColumn(name = "address")
   private Address address;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Address{
   
   @Id
   private Long id;
   
   private String state;
}
```

All the examples that I can see on the internet point to update query with String, int, ...
I am looking a way to update the query where I can pass the custom associated objects.

```java
@Modifying
@Query("update Person p set p.address =: address)
void update(@Param(value = "address") Address address)
```

is it possible? I have tried with **EntityManager**, **save()** method of JPA as well, but I am looking for the above kind of JPQL query.

Comment: whats with `@Query("update Person p set p.address =: address)`? Have you tried it? Of course it needs a `where` clause to narrow down the update else it will update all Persons in database and there is a small type in `=: address`, it needs to be `= :address` and a closing double quote `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will update all `Person` entities' address.

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("update Person p set p.address = :address")
void update(@Param(value = "address") Address address)
```

Note the @Transactional annotation and make sure that the `Address address` parameter should not be transient, i.e. should already exist in database and fetch it from there

i.e.

```
Address address = new Address();
address.setState("blabla");
Address savedAddress = addressRepository.save(address);

personRepository.update(savedAddress); // use the peristed Address entity here.
```

Comment: in case of updating already present address first we need to fetch the specific address associated with person from db, alter its state, save the address and then update person. I have put cascade = CascadeType.ALL still i need to first save address and then update person else i get transient state exception. Any way to avoid the boiler plate code of fetching address, updating and saving it and then updating person